# How to fix DEPRECATION WARNING: Class level methods will no longer inherit scoping from in Rails 6.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, deprecation-warning, ruby-on-rails-6

Recently updated my Rails app to 6.0.  When I run my tests I get the following deprecation warning from a scope on my `Referral` model:

```rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: Class level methods will no longer inherit scoping from `with_all_final_state_fulfillments` in Rails 6.1. To continue using the scoped relation, pass it into the block directly. To instead access the full set of models, as Rails 6.1 will, use `Referral.unscoped`. (called from block in <class:Referral> at /Users/home/workspace/APPNAME/app/models/referral.rb:60)
```

My `Referral` model scope in question is hacky, but written like this:

```rb
  scope :with_all_final_state_fulfillments, lambda {
    final_state_ids = Referral.with_fulfillment_in_final_state.pluck(:id).uniq
    not_final_state_ids = Referral.where(id: final_state_ids).with_fulfillment_not_in_final_state.pluck(:id).uniq

    id_list = final_state_ids - not_final_state_ids
    Referral.where(id: id_list)
  }
```

I've searched all around the internet for advice on how to fix this deprecation, [including](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35186) [the Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35280) GitHub PR's making the change, but haven't found a clear [English explanation](https://qiita.com/MasamotoMiyata/items/8f1eda27daee69911e0f) anywhere.

How do I fix this deprecated scope for Rail 6.1?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Made the deprecation warning go away by updating inside scope calls of `Referral.` to `self.`:

```rb
  scope :with_all_final_state_fulfillments, lambda {
    final_state_ids = self.with_fulfillment_in_final_state.pluck(:id).uniq
    not_final_state_ids = self.where(id: final_state_ids).with_fulfillment_not_in_final_state.pluck(:id).uniq

    id_list = final_state_ids - not_final_state_ids
    where(id: id_list)
  }
```

Comment: Another possible solution may have been to use [Referral.default_scoped.x](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35280#issuecomment-585516268)